# How to access HTML Elements with "load" in mootools core?

Tags: javascript, html, mootools, joomla-extensions

whether the load on the mootools will access the html element?
I try to access the html element named class = repliesList, in my code there

var tabs = getElementsByClass ('repliesList');
alert(tabs);

but tabs variable print only blank, how to join loaded html element?
I've tried using domready, but does not run at all, even printing something that is on alert was not.

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mootools then why don't you are using [mootools selectors](http://solutoire.com/2007/09/20/understanding-mootools-selectors-e-and-es/).

you can access element by $$('.repliesList'). What you wronn in you code is you are missing "document" word write `document.getElementsByClass('repliesList');`

But You should prefer mootools selectors

Comment: this is probably a custom function he has so applying it to document is not going to work. in vanilla js the method is called  `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementsByClass`, and only if it's supported at that (not at all cross browser).

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEvent("domready", function() {
    // be more deffinitive in the selectors. eg all LI with class repliesList:
    var tabs = document.getElements("li.repliesList"); // will work in all versions of mootools
    // for 1.12 (old joomla) you can use $$("li.repliesList") 

    // to be faster still - if all the tabs are children of say, ul id="menu"
    var tabs = $("menu").getElements("li.repliesList");        

    // don't alert an elements collection. get FireBug or similar and:
    console.log(tabs);

    tabs.each(function(tab) {
        // do something with each tab like tab.addEvents() etc
    });
}); // end domready
```